# Include Columns from a Blank table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple Sql with outer joins joining 8 tables-where table6 is blank.
By 
There are no indexes **on any of the tables**.  If there are no indexes on any of the tables then why is this table's column causing the query time to increase substantially?
As soon as I **include** the column from table6(blank tables/no rows), the query execution time jumps from 2 to 28 seconds.
Whereas by just excluding table6 column from select still keeping the outer join to table6, the execution time still remains at 2/3 seconds.
What could be the reason for it?
By **Null Table**, I just meant blank table-Updated the subject to reflect the same.

```
SELECT  u.UserID,u.LastName,
        CAST(t1.Hours  as Int) as t1Hours
        ,CAST(t2.Hours as Int) as t2Hours 
        ,CAST(t3.Hours_as Int) as t3Hours
        ,CAST(t4.Hours as Int) as t4Hours
        ,CAST(t5.Hours as Int) as t5Hours
        ,CAST(t6.Hours as Int) as t6Hours
        ,a.CYear
FROM    Users u
            LEFT OUTER JOIN     table1 t1 ON u.UserID = t1.UserID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN     table2 t2 ON u.UserID = t2.UserID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN     table3 t3 ON u.UserID = t3.UserID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN     table4 t4 ON u.UserID = t4.UserID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN     table5 t5 ON u.UserID = t5.UserID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN     table6 t6 ON u.UserID = t6.UserID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN     A a       ON u.UserID = a.Login 
    WHERE   u.DepID = 1 and u.RoleID=1
    Order By a.CYear desc , u.LastName asc
```

Thanks.

Comment: `What could be the reason for it?` *`There are no indexes on any of the tables.`*

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by a "Null table"?

Comment: Look at query plan and if that doesn't solve it, post both before & after plans here. Why don't you have indexes?

Comment: Regardless of whether you have a JOIN or not, if the query doesn't need to use it (e.g. no SELECT, ORDER BY, WHERE or other JOINs etc. rely on it) then SQL Server is intelligent enough *not* to make the join.  Presumably your inefficiency is due to lack of indexing.

Comment: The reason is because the execution plan changes.  I'm not sure what the changes are, but either doing the joins in a different order or switching from hash-joins to nested loop joins are the two likely culprits.

Comment: Please see my answers above.

Comment: Take a look at the execution plan, it should become clear.

Comment: Changing Join to a different order decreased the execution time from 28 to 13 seconds.